# Having trouble creating an ArcGIS Pro LAS dataset profile view like ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d-analyst, las, elevation-profile

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.3 and am looking for a way to view a slice of LiDAR data side-on, like the ArcMap [LAS Dataset Profile Tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/las-dataset/las-dataset-profile-view.htm) not rotated in 3d; I have 3d analyst and Advanced licenses.

I have previously used the profile tool in ArcMap to view (only) areas that are suspicious to identify locations that have clouds or atmospheric noise that are not correctly classified as *high noise*. I have searched [the documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/profile-viewing.htm) which refers to scenes but they don't look like what I'm after.

Is there a way to (shortcut) navigate an ArcGIS Pro scene profile to side-on or is there a new/different tool that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't use LAS but I know you can [link](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/navigation/introduction-to-linked-views.htm) a 2D map with a 3D scene, so you have your birds eye view in 2D and the profile views in the scene, that might be the nearest equivalent to the ArcMap tool?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Hornbydd, I've tried that and it's less than optimal. I need to view only a narrow slice where the X axis is length along a user drawn line and the Y axis is absolute height, restricted to minimum and maximum height of the subsample of LiDAR records.

Comment: Could you create your narrow slice by filtering based on the coordinates - like a definition query, so you don't have to view the remaining non-slice records?

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion @ycartwhelen, if the LAS dataset has shape (geometry object) exposed trimming to an extent would be possible but the profile is diagonal, it is possible to draw a line, buffer it and then include/exclude using within extent (fast) followed by inside buffer, I'll give that a shot and see if it's a workable.